# Restore purchase with InAppBillingPlugin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I am currently using the InAppBillingPlugin from James Montemagno to deploy a subscription program in my app.

It works fine but I need to make a restore purchase feature in the app and I encountered a problem with this.

I have followed the process explained on the [documentation](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/CheckAndRestorePurchases.html) but when I call the function GetPurchaseAsync(), there's nothing in the Enumerable object I get.

[image: You can see the complete object in the picture]

I tried with my real apple store account, I bought a product with the actual app in production and tried to restore my purchase with my app in development.

If anyone knows how I can correct this, it would be very helpful!

Comment: What i would do when something unexpected happens with a lib is download its source code, include with my project to fully debug what's happening inside and why..

Comment: You can't restore purchase on development when you have purchased on production. Both have separate InApp Purchase URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your real apple account to test the production app in the development environment. It won't work.
If you want to test your In-App Purchase with development environment. Please change your apple account to Test User Accounts and use sandbox environment. About how to create your app's own test account you can refer to: [Create a sandbox tester account](http://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev8b997bee1). 
Note that the text “[Environment: Sandbox]” appears as part of the prompt, indicating that you’re connected to the test environment. More details about how to Retrieving Product Information please see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW11).

Comment: Thank you, I know the sandbox and I already tried with it but the enumerables purchases contain only purchases without any PurchaseToken, that's why I try with the production In App Purchase...

Comment: @nicar you can try to share some code about the purchases you get, I think we can get the information we need in the sandbox.

Comment: The code I used to allow to restore purchases :

`var purchases = await billing.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);
foreach(var purchase in purchases)
{
   if (purchase.PurchaseToken != null)`

The code in the last "if" is never called and when I look in purchases, I can see this : [Purchase Enumerable](https://imgur.com/upIGZBs)
All of the objects sent back contain exactly the same thing with the same TransactionDateUtc, only the ID is different. Which doesn't make sense as those purchases in sandbox were done on different days.

Comment: @nicar the product ID is same too?

Comment: @nicar We just need product ID to restore user's bought product.

Comment: yes, on my picture the product ID is the same as the product ID in the app, I don't check it in my code because there's no purchase that contain PurchaseToken, so it's not relevant. If I can see one purchase with PurchaseToken, I check the product ID before sending it to my backend but actually it doesn't make sense.
Another thing you can see on my picture is that there's many times the same product ID because this account made a lot of different purchases, so I can't use all products with this info to restore the purchase...

Comment: @nicar I'm still confused about what you want. As I know, if we can get the productID, we just can know which product user has bought. Then we can restore the products.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162154/discussion-between-nicar-and-land).